# htaccess logic not working in vhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html|js|ico|pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_loader.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_loader.php/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page_loader.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I have run a Debian server with Apache 2.2.

I have a system that routes all traffic through a file named *page_loader.php*.

When I run the above in a *.htaccess* file there are no problems, but as soon as I try to put it in the vhost file directly Apache fails to restart and just says `FAIL` but without anything in the log files.

Has anyone else had anything like this?

Comment: check the file. correct saved? Whats in the VHost?

Comment: When have errors in .htaccess, browser display a 500 server error when you access a page than use this. Maybe you have other problem in apache conf. Check the apache error.log. Check too if you have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: gabrieloliveira is right, the problem isn't your htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are putting that in your Apache config file directly, `RewriteBase` only works inside `<directory>` directive. If you don't do that it will fail to start.

```
<Directory "/var/www/path/to/doc/root">
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html|js|ico|pdf)$
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_loader.php$
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page_loader.php/
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page_loader.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</Directory >
```